# Java 8 use Lambda/Method reference dynamic

Tags: java, generics, dynamic, lambda

I'm going to use java 8 and all its power to migrate my code.

I want to use dynamically the lambda expressions or the method references.

For example, I want to pass the dynamic method to call as function parameter, and use it in lambda after.

```
public <T> List<?> getDynamic(List<T> objects, ?????? myFilter, ??????? myMapper) {
    objects.stream()
      .filter(myFilter)
      .map(myMapper)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

getDynamic(customerList, Customer::isEnabled, Customer::getCustomerId);
getDynamic(customerList, c -> c.isEnabled(), c -> getCustomerId());
```

Any way to do that or to find any replacement?

**--------- EDIT 1 ---------**

Thanks for the solutions.

But I forgot one case. I need to have the method name dynamic too.

```
public <T> List<?> getDynamic(List<T> objects, String myMethodSimpleMapper) {
    objects.stream()
      .map(T::myMethodSimpleMapper) <------ HOW ?
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

getDynamic(customerList, "getCustomerId");
```

I have some properties stored in classes or enums (as descriptors). I need to use them to manipulate data automatically, using only these properties (String).
Some cases are very simple, and I have property names (I can maybe deduce the associated getters).

Is it possible too using lambdas or method references?

Comment: `Predicate<? super T> myFilter`, `Function<? super T, ?> myMapper`.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to pass the method in as a string?

Comment: Yes, it's for some conventionnal classes that describe my interfaces.
So i use "descriptors" like enums saying which field is used, visible, editable, etc in my forms and tables.
The only way i found to get that is to use the field name as key of my DTO field to manage.

Comment: What do you mean by "conventional" classes?

Comment: SOrry for my english ... Classes using an internally defined convention.

Answer (score 4):

A good way to figure this out is see what `filter` and `map` accept as a parameter.

[image]

We see that `filter` wants a `Predicate<? super T>` and `map` wants a `Function<? super T, ? extends R>`.

Now we just need to figure out what that `R` is.

Since you want your method to return a `List<?>`, we need to map the result to `?`. So `R` is `?`. So the type of `mapper` should be `Function<? super T, ? extends ?>`, which is just `Function<? super T, ?>`.

This is your method:

```
public <T> List<?> getDynamic(List<T> objects, Predicate<? super T> myFilter, Function<? super T, ?> myMapper) {
    return objects.stream()
            .filter(myFilter)
            .map(myMapper)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However, I think returning a `List<?>` is not very useful. I would suggest that you add another generic parameter `R` and return a `List<R>` it would be more useful. This is just my personal opinion though, feel free to not do this.

```
public <T, R> List<R> getDynamic(List<T> objects, Predicate<? super T> myFilter, Function<? super T, ? extends R> myMapper) {
    return objects.stream()
            .filter(myFilter)
            .map(myMapper)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```